# How to display different form for different countries?

Tags: forms, paypal, ip, locale

How to display different form for different countries?

I am trying to find a way to display **different registration forms for different countries**, by automatically identify user's ip address.

I looked at these with no luck:
[Paypal buttons with different prices depending on country](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15686453/paypal-buttons-with-different-prices-depending-on-country)

[Can I use PayPal to change product prices based on location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18040187/can-i-use-paypal-to-change-product-prices-based-on-location?rq=1)

I have done extensive research on Stackoverflow and other platforms, and tried many implementations. Please, can you assist with my below code, and point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PayPal does not host registration forms; PayPal processes payments.  What you describe can be done in your own custom/dynamic code. The user will then end up at PayPal for the final payment step.

Comment: I appreciate your reply. My own custom/dynamic code will be in php? How will I research this and please can you recommend any resource?

Comment: Honestly that's more of a "How do I learn to be a web developer?" question, rather than a specific question we can help with